# Win 10 and other software CPUz is showing 4 RAM slots in my Acer Aspire 5740 laptop, bought in 2009

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, memory

In Win 7 as well as Win 10 using software like CPUz, it is showing 4 RAM slots in my Acer Aspire 5740 laptop, bought in Sept-2009. In Win 10, task manager also gives us RAM, CPU, HDD info.There i found, 4 RAM slots. Is it possible to have 4 RAM slots in laptop? To confirm this, I disassemble my laptop completely once, not able to find out rest of the two RAM slots. Why it is showing then in my laptop?

Comment: the data come from SMBIOS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) and it returns wrong data

Answer (score -1):

Where in Windows 7 and Windows 10 did you see you have 4 slots? They will only list the available total memory.

As for CPU-Z, you can go to the SPD tab, and check if all slots have memory details in them. If you find only two have details, and the other two are empty, you can safely assume it's just an erroneous listing from the program.

On my laptop for instance, which has two slots, CPU-Z lists 4 slots, with #1 and #3 used, while #2 and #4 are empty (non-existent).

Comment: CPU-Z software shows 4 RAM slot in windows 7 & 10. And in Win 10, we can get some details in taskbar. There also i found same. I am agree with you that may be it shows non-existant slots, but why?

Comment: If you have a dual channel capable memory controller then it is quite common to use slot 1&3 and 2&4 in pairs. (Of for triple channel 1&4&7, 2&5&8, 3&6&9).  Thus keeping the slot numbers consistent within a range even though this particular laptop does not support it) might be a reason.

Comment: Hi Hennes, As per results shown in CPUz in Memory Tab: Type- DDR3, Channel# - Dual, Size- 8 GB, DC Mode- Symmetric. In SPD Tab results are: Total Slots: 4, Slot 1 & 2 each having 4 GB RAM, and slot 3 & 4 -  no Information (blank). Could you pls explain this result. you can see validation result on : http://valid.x86.fr/bry2ai

Comment: Your validation is not showing up. But as already explained, The SPD tab does not show the number of physical slots. There are various reasons why it's incorrect, but it IS incorrect on most computers. My laptop has 2 slots, it shows them as #1 and #3, while #2 and #4 are empty. My Desktop has 2 slots, it shows #2 and #4 have ram, while #1 and #3 are empty, yet they don't exist.

Comment: It could depend on how they are numbered in the SMBios, it could depend on the actual circuitry of the board, it could depend on the max supported by BIOS/SMBios/CPU.